# Let $E\subseteq[a,b]$ be measurable. Prove that $\overline mA=\overline m(A\cap E) + \overline m(A\cap E^c)$ for any $A\subseteq[a,b]$.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, proof-writing, lebesgue-measure

> Let $E\subseteq[a,b]$ be measurable. Prove that $\overline mA=\overline m(A\cap E) + \overline m(A\cap E^c)$ for any $A\subseteq[a,b]$.

I am having a little bit of trouble proving this claim. Here $\overline mA$ denotes the *outer measure* of $A$. The hint that my textbook provides is to use the following theorem:

> **THEOREM** ($\epsilon$-criterion for Measurability): The subset $E\subseteq[a,b]$ is measurable if and only for any $\epsilon > 0$ there exist open sets $\mathcal O_1,\mathcal O_2$ such that $E\subseteq\mathcal O_1, E^c\subseteq\mathcal O_2$, and $|\mathcal O_1\cap\mathcal O_2| < \epsilon$.

Here's what I know: I know that $\mathcal |O_1\cap\mathcal O_2| = |\mathcal O_1| + |\mathcal O_2| - |\mathcal O_1\cup\mathcal O_2|$, and $A = (A\setminus E)\cup(A\setminus E^c)$.

I cannot use subadditivity of outer measurability because such a result has not been introduced. If I *could*, then I manage to get $\le$ fairly quickly:

$$\overline m(A) = \overline m[(A\cap E)\cup(A\cap E^c)] \le \overline m(A\cap E) + \overline m(A\cap E^c).$$ The other direction is unclear, however. Can someone provide a hint as to what I might need to do?

Comment: I have never seen that way defining measurability. Generally I have seen sets to be measurable if they belong to a some sigma algebra, which in the case of R is taken as the borel sigma algebra.

Comment: I can try to see into the problem if you help me out with what other definitions you have. |A| gives the measure of A? Is the outermeasure defined as the infimum of added measures of possible countable covers?

Comment: @Juanito. There are a number of equivalent def'ns of Lebesgue meaurability,  and some authors seem to prefer a def'n that others would prefer to call a theorem. Sometimes this goes too far, in my opinion.  You could introduce $e$ as the unique $r>0$ such that $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}r^{-x^2}dx=\sqrt {\pi}$ but this  would not be good pedagogy. unless your only student is S. Ramanujan.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fortunately been able to solve the problem!

Here, I will need to use a lemma which I will call **Lemma** $\star$.

> **Lemma** $\star$: If $G_1, G_2$ are open subsets of $[a,b]$, then $$|G_1| + |G_2| = |G_1\cup G_2| + |G_1\cap G_2|.$$

I will not prove Lemma $\star$ here because it should be fairly straightforward. Now to the main result:

**PROOF**: We begin by letting $E\subseteq[a,b]$ be measurable, and $A\subseteq[a,b]$ be any subset. Let $\epsilon > 0$ be given. By the $\epsilon$-criterion for measurability, there exist open sets $\mathcal O_1, \mathcal O_2$ such that $E\subseteq\mathcal O_1$, $E^c\subseteq\mathcal O_2$ and $|\mathcal O_1\cap\mathcal O_2|<{\epsilon\over2}$ **(1)**.

From the definition of outer measure, there exists an open set $G$ such that $A\subseteq G$ and $|G| < \overline m(A) + {\epsilon\over2}$ **(2)**. Then, $$\begin{align*}\overline m(A\cap E)+\overline m(A\cap E^c) &\le |G\cap\mathcal O_1| + |G\cap\mathcal O_2|\\ &= |(G\cap\mathcal O_1)\cup(G\cap\mathcal O_2)| \; +\\ &\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\; |(G\cap\mathcal O_1)\cap(G\cap\mathcal O_2)| \tag{$\star$}\\ &= \underbrace{|G\cap(\mathcal O_1\cup\mathcal O_2)|}_\text{De Morgan's Laws} + |G\cap\mathcal O_1\cap\mathcal O_2| \\ &\le |G| + |\mathcal O_1\cap\mathcal O_2|\\ & < \left[\overline m(A) + {\epsilon\over2}\right] + {\epsilon \over2} \tag{By (1) and (2)}\\ &=\overline m(A) + \epsilon.\end{align*}$$ By letting $\epsilon \to 0$, we obtain the desired result. $\square$

---

If you are confused about how I apply the step $\star$ in this proof, I basically say that $G_1 = (G\cap \mathcal O_1)$ and $G_2 = (G\cap\mathcal O_2)$ (recall that the intersection of two open sets is open). Then $$|G_1| + |G_2| = \underbrace{|G_1\cup G_2|}_{(G\cap\mathcal O_1)\cup(G\cap\mathcal O_2)} + \underbrace{|G_1\cap G_2|.}_{(G\cap\mathcal O_1)\cap(G\cap\mathcal O_2)}$$